# Can you have a subfield whose unity is different from the unity of the larger field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Suppose we have a field $F$ and a (non trivial) subring $R$ of $F$ which does not contain $1$, yet has an element $a$ such that for all $r$ in $R$, $ar = r$ and there exists $q$ in $R$ such that $rq = a$. Clearly $R$ is a field with unity $a$. Can a field have such a subring, though? If so, I'd love to see an example.

Comment: As you can see in the answers, this is not possible. By the way, if you have  that $F$ is not a field, but simply a ring, then this is possible. For example, the subset $R=\{ 0,2 \} \subset \Bbb{Z} /6 \Bbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication, and the element $2$ has the role of a unity, so $R$ is a field.

Comment: @Crostul Do you mean $R=\{0,3\}$?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, I meant $R= \{ 0,3 \}$. It is a typo (I had in mind $3=6/2$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $r = a r $ and $r \ne 0$, then $1 = r^{-1} r = \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming commutativity in the following (should I not?). Let us suppose there is such an element $a$, and let $b\in R$ be such $ab=a$ (the inverse of $a$ in $R$).

Denoting by $a^{-1}$ the inverse of $a$ in $F$, you get 
$b=a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}a=1$. So $1=b\in R$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see it.